# Remove everything except for first 3 words of a line in Notepad++

Tags: replace, formatting, notepad++

I have a lengthy text document and I would like to remove everything except for the first 3 words of each line.  I've seen a few answered questions that allow you to do this but only retaining the first word.  I'm just wondering if it is possible with the first 3 instead.  Here is an example:

(original)

```
hello how are you today
this is just a test
today is a great day
```

(what I would like to keep)

```
hello how are
this is just
today is a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\w+\h+\w+\h+\w+\K.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal space
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal space
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
    \K          # forget all we have seen until this position
    .*          # 1 or more any character but newline
$
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]